# Attaching username given and removing undefined from an Alert box

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have tried to make my username that I enabled in my html page to be attached to *welcome again!*  but the prompt box keeps returning
*welcome again!undefined*
onsubmit instead of *welcome again!Akan* for example

My **setCookie** and **getCookie** functions are working just fine

This are the html and Js codes which concern this problem, respectively

```html
<form action="Home.html" method="form" onsubmit="return checkCookie()">
  Name: <input type="text" name="username" size="40"\>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" \>
<\form>
```

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdate) {
    let exd=new Date();
        exd.setTime(exd.getTime()+ (exdate*24*60*60*1000));
    let expires= 'expires=' + exd.toUTCString();

    document.cookie=cname + '=' +cvalue +';' +expires +';path=/';  
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    if (document.cookie.length>0) {
        cstart=document.cookie.indexOf(cname + '=');
        if (cstart !=-1) {
            cstart= cstart+ cname.length+1
            cend= document.cookie.indexOf(cstart ,';');
        if (cend==-1) {
            cend=document.cookie.length;
        return 
            unescape(document.cookie.substring(cstart,cend));
        }
        }
        return "";
    }
}

function checkCookie() {
    let username=getCookie('username').value;

    if (username!='') {
        alert('Welcome again!'+ username);
    } else {
        username=prompt('Please enter your name:' ,'');
        if (username!='') {
            setCookie('username',username,365);
        }
    }
}
```

Your help will be appreciated

Comment: Also to close html tags you use `</tag>` and you are using `<\tag>` which is weird.

Comment: Thanks, noted... I had to type it out thus some errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: getCookie is undefined.
Second: form in this example is not needed.

```js
function checkCookie() {
  let username = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;

  if (username != '') {
    alert ('welcome again!' + username);
    document.querySelector('#my-form').submit();
  } else {
    username = prompt('Input your name:', '');
    if (username != '') {
      setCookie('username', username, 365);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  Name: <input type="text" name="username" size="40"/>
  <input type="button" onclick="checkCookie()" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: It worked here...but wasn't responsive in the main code

Comment: see the snippet code changes. Javascript can run submit programmaticaly.